# Umbraco 7 custom property editor using angular file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, umbraco, property-editor

I am using [angular file upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) in a custom property editor for Umbraco 7.0.3. I am following [this tutorial](http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/tutorials/CreatingAPropertyEditor) in order to create the editor.

I am quite new to angular, so my question maybe trivial for some of you: I cannot resolve dependency to file upload service in my controller soon enough. My HTML template looks like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCustomController">
    <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
</div>
```

The controller function would need $upload service as an argument, however I inject that service at the beginning of the function:

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("MyCustomController", function ($scope, assetService, $upload) {

    assetsService
        .load([
            "/App_Plugins/MyCustomPlugin/angular-file-upload.min.js",
        ])
        .then(function () {
            alert('upload service loaded');
        });

    $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
        alert('file selected');
    }
});
```

So, it is definitely not right this way. I was trying to load the upload service before the controller initialization, however it loads asynchronously, so the service cannot get defined before the controller anyway.

How can I declare my controller function only after the upload service is loaded, or how can I get a reference to the service other than an argument?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

The only solution I've found so far was to include the actual file upload codebase into the controller of the custom property editor. I used [this paper](http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) as a starting point for my own codebase for its simplicity. However I am still looking for the 'proper' way of loading an external module in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Include your code as a service instead.

The code angular.module line can take extra parameters if you see [its documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module). It is here that you should look to include any third party libs. For example, I use ngTable - an AngularJS wrapper around a jQuery sortable and filterable table plugin. To include its usage, I have to add it as a *service* to the current application's module like so:

```
var app = angular.module("umbraco", ['ngTable']);
```

All I then have to remember to do is to reference the scripts, and I can use the code as though I had included the body of the code itself. Therefore, I presume that you would reference your service JS files, and write your code to reference the service like this:

```
angular.module("umbraco", "MyCustomController");
```

I would however rename the code as [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) rather than controllers.

It's a steep learning curve for AngularJS, and even when you've used it a lot, there are a lot of common gotchas. I hope this explains it a bit more.